# Where do I put Access vba code to only fire when physically printing?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have some code that I want to fire when the user physically prints the report.  Not when Print Previewing, etc, but only when sending to the printer.  The user needs to be able to pull up the report and view it, then if they decide to print, the vba code will take over and write some info to a different table than is being used to generate the report.  I was hoping not to have to place a Print button on the actual report (even though I know I can hide it for the print), so I was wondering if I could somehow trap the Print dialog instead.

Has anyone ever had any luck doing so?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own code into the print button?

Comment: @Remou, I have considered that (see above), but I was hoping that I could catch the event from File --> Print, or Ctrl-P. I worry that user will just use the traditional methods of printing and not use MY print button.

Comment: What I was thinking is that you change the print button on the menu to your own macro. You can reassign the menu buttons, so the only button the user can choose is your button. Similarly, you can create your own right-click menu.

Comment: Did you want to prevent the users from being able to perform a manual print or would you like to just perform an additional action when the document is sent to the printer? I would suggest monitoring the print spool with the Form's Timer event and if the document name appears, perform the requested action. [Take a look at this code.](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=183)

Comment: @nicholaus - I like the thought process, but if I am looking for document name and someone else is using the database to print the same report (for a different item) to the same printer (which they will), then this would fire on the incorrect record.  I could get aorund it by renaming the document before printing...

Comment: I guess I should ask about the hardware configuration. Are all users printing to a shared network printer? Do users have multiple printers installed on their machine? - it would be easier if you were monitoring a single print spool - also regarding document name and users, theoretically a document in queue will also show the user name

Comment: @nicholaus - There is a possibility that printers will be shared, but also that they will be unique to the user.  As an example, 4 people using laptops in a production envrionment that share a single printer on the floor, but the supervisor is in his office and has access to the shared printer as well as a desktop right next to him.  So, the 4 prod people would share and have the same issue as I described in my above comment, but the supervisor runs into the issue of having multiple spools to monitor.

Comment: I suppose you are limited to using Access/VBA? I was doing a little more research and see that this task definitely can be done by invoking winspool.drv functions; however, it would be **much** easier using the System.Printing class in .NET.

Comment: It is by no means difficult to customize and create your own menus. In addition, reports and forms have a menu property.

Comment: @nicholaus, definitely constrained to Access/VBA at this point.  DEfinitely want to migrate to .NET.

Comment: @Remou, I am looking at that right now.  I have created menus before, but never to supplant what is currently there (more like add-on menus).  I will let you know shortly if I think it is workable on my end.

Comment: I have not got a version with menu bars at the moment, but I remember customising the buttons to pun my functions, so instead of, say mnuPrint, the Action is set to MyFunction.

Comment: Instead of the tricky task of monitoring the print spooler, I thought of what would be different during the Page() event. Answer: the caption of the active window.

Comment: @Remou, In the short time that I created my menu, macros and functions, I determined that it will work.  THe difficult part is that I could not easily figure out how to override Ctrl-P without removing the standard toolbar first, which the end user(s) won't like.  However +1 for the solution for future problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much consideration, I think the best way to accomplish this is by identifying the Active Window text during the report Page event. During a print preview, this text will be the name of the database itself, something like "Microsoft Access - DatabaseName : Database (Access 2003). During a real printing operation, the active window will be "Printing"

I credit most of the code as coming from [this source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141354%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

```
Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
   (ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Sub Report_Page()
On Error GoTo PrintError

    Dim strCaption As String
       Dim lngLen   As Long

       ' Create string filled with null characters.
       strCaption = String$(255, vbNullChar)
       ' Return length of string.
       lngLen = Len(strCaption)

       ' Call GetActiveWindow to return handle to active window,
       ' and pass handle to GetWindowText, along with string and its length.
       If (GetWindowText(GetActiveWindow, strCaption, lngLen) > 0) Then
          ' Return value that Windows has written to string.
          ActiveWindowCaption = strCaption
       End If

    If ActiveWindowCaption = "Printing" Then

        '
        ' Special activity goes here.
        '

    End If

    Exit Sub

PrintError:
    ' Just in case

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and I didn't have to add anything other than the Lib functions for GetActiveWindow and GetWindowText.  Thanks!

Comment: The only limitation to this approach is that it only allows actions to be performed after the print spooling has begun. If the intention was to intercept the print action and run a function before spooling, it would require menu / ribbon customization as @Remou proposed.

Comment: I agree.  @Remou's works for pre-printing processing; this works for post-printing.  I was looking for post-printing for this, but Remou's solution will be useful in future.

Comment: @but for me appearing window with title "Printing" was too swift and thus this code failed so I added an artificial wait/sleep to be succeeded on this code.

Answer (score 0):

use the following declarations for the above answer instead:

```
#If VBA7 Then
     Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
     Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
#End If
```