# Hiding Report Fields on Print

Tags: ms-access, printing, vba, ms-access-2003

In an Access 2003 database, I have an employee status/feedback report that is generated through VBA. I create the report in VBA because the desired formatting of report is such that I found it to be easier for me to do it this way (combining multiple recordsets, displaying more than one record from a recordset aligned with others, customizing some formatting elements based on department, etc.). There may be a better way to create these reports, but this is functioning just fine, so I'd rather avoid recreating if possible.

My problem is this: As this is an employee feedback form, there are details that supervisors want to be able to see, but not show the employee. When the report is generated, the supervisor has a chance to review the data/make changes from the report itself (via userforms, event handling on the report). Part of the review is to look at one set of fields (added to the report as labels), but these fields should be hidden when the report is ultimately printed.

In my head, I thought I had seen before a way to hide specific controls in this way and did some googling to find [this MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195851%28office.11%29.aspx) on `DisplayWhen`. However, it appears that `DisplayWhen` is usable only on forms. Is there a way to set this value (or similar/related option) using reports?  Doing a search on SO, I found only one single question in a query for **DisplayWhen**, which was not helpful to me.

Using `.Visible = False` on the creation of the report of the report won't work because the supervisors will need to see those fields. It does not appear that I can set this property upon printing, as I see no event handling option for this. Can I create a custom event handler that will capture the print command?

Here's the control creation code:

```
Private Sub AddOneOnOneField(Rpt As Report, Left As Integer, Top As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer, _
    Optional Cap As String = vbNullString, Optional Align As Integer = cnFontCenter, Optional Size As Integer = 10, _
    Optional Bold As Integer = cnBoldFont, Optional DisplayWhen As Byte = 0)

    With CreateReportControl(Rpt.Name, acLabel, acDetail, vbNullString, vbNullString, _
        Left, Top, Width, Height)

        .Properties("FontSize") = Size
        .Properties("FontWeight") = Bold
        .Properties("BorderStyle") = 1
        .Properties("TextAlign") = Align
        .Properties("Caption") = Cap
        .Properties("DisplayWhen") = DisplayWhen ' This does not work!
    End With

End Sub
```

---

*To reiterate my questions:*

- **How can I set certain report fields to only display on print preview, but not on print?**
- **Can I create a custom event handler that will capture the print command from a report?**
- **Is there a way to set the `DisplayWhen` property (or similar/related option) on a report field?**

Comment: Why would you want it to display on print preview if you don't want it to print? Isn't that rather misleading?

Comment: @DanielCook My understanding is the only way to see the report is to view it in print preview or edit mode, and I don't want them editing the report. I would like to display on screen something different than what prints out. The supervisors want additional info the summary at a glance that they want to keep hidden from the employees. They can get this data elsewhere, but I'm trying to put it into this report for their convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not ideal, but it works. When creating the report through VBA, I already had code to create code within the report module. I added to that function to capture the print/force hiding of the fields, print, then un-hide.

```
Private Sub AddReportCode(mdlNew As Module)
Dim sNewCode As String

    sNewCode = "Option Compare Database" & vbCr & "Option Explicit"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "Public Sub CapturePrint()"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "Dim v As Variant"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "If Application.CurrentObjectName = ""OneOnOneReport"" And Application.CurrentObjectType = acReport Then"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "DoCmd.OpenReport ""OneOnOneReport"", acViewDesign"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "Reports(""OneOnOneReport"").Visible = False"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "For Each v In Reports(""OneOnOneReport"").Controls"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "If Left(v.Properties(""Name""), 3) = ""Occ"" Then"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "v.Visible = False"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "End If"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "Next v"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "DoCmd.OpenReport ""OneOnOneReport"", acNormal"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "DoCmd.OpenReport ""OneOnOneReport"", acViewDesign"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "For Each v In Reports(""OneOnOneReport"").Controls"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "If Left(v.Properties(""Name""), 4) = ""HIDE"" Then"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "v.Visible = True"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "End If"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "Next v"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "Reports(""OneOnOneReport"").Visible = True"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "DoCmd.OpenReport ""OneOnOneReport"", acViewPreview"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "End If"
    sNewCode = sNewCode & vbCr & "End Sub"

    mdlNew.DeleteLines 1, mdlNew.CountOfLines

    mdlNew.InsertText sNewCode

End Sub
```

For readability, here's the actual code that is in the module after this runs:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub CapturePrint()
Dim v As Variant
If Application.CurrentObjectName = "OneOnOneReport" And Application.CurrentObjectType = acReport Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "OneOnOneReport", acViewDesign
    Reports("OneOnOneReport").Visible = False
    For Each v In Reports("OneOnOneReport").Controls
        If Left(v.Properties("Name"), 3) = "Occ" Then
            v.Visible = False
        End If
    Next v
    DoCmd.OpenReport "OneOnOneReport", acNormal
    DoCmd.OpenReport "OneOnOneReport", acViewDesign
    For Each v In Reports("OneOnOneReport").Controls
        If Left(v.Properties("Name"), 4) = "HIDE" Then
            v.Visible = True
        End If
    Next v
    Reports("OneOnOneReport").Visible = True
    DoCmd.OpenReport "OneOnOneReport", acViewPreview
End If
End Sub
```

When adding new controls to the report (see original code in question body), I added the ability to optionally assign a name to the control:

```
.Properties("Name") = NewName
```

The control creation code was called with a `NewName` argument of `"HIDE" & ControlTop & ControlLeft` to allow for naming all the needed controls without duplicating names. Before hiding, the report is opened in design mode to prevent screen flickering/slowdown. The printing code then cycles through all the controls on the report looking for names starting with "HIDE" and hides them. Once all controls are hidden, the report is reopened as normal to print, then the process repeats to unhide these controls and display the original report to the user.

I still was not able to capture the `print` event properly (and this is where the solution becomes not my favorite option), so instead I prompted the user at the initial creation of the report to print, calling the newly created `CapturePrint` Sub (while hiding those fields). If they opt not to, then they can print as normal without hiding the fields, or regenerate the report to hide them/be prompted again.

Answer (score 1):

If hiding the data is really important, you have chosen the wrong database, if it is somewhat casual, you can ask administrators to enter a code and either hide or display the fields based on the code. Alternatively, you can supply administrators with a slightly different front-end.

Comment: Please see my comment to Daniel Cook on the question.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347139/where-do-i-put-access-vba-code-to-only-fire-when-physically-printing

Comment: I was able to work with the idea of customizing the menu functions, but had some trouble with capturing all the possible methods of printing. I resolved the issue on my own and have posted as an answer here.

Comment: Also, to explain a little better why I didn't take your initial suggestion: This DB front end is only accessed by the supervisors. The employees only have the ability to see some of the data in their own, entirely different front end. That being said, there was no other front end to design/permissions to worry about. I was only concerned with the printing on report for one piece of data. But thanks for the tip; I may use it in the future.